# How to fetch data from same class for different objects

Tags: javascript, html, object, extjs

I have a two component in ExtJS. I am creating one class separately.

```
{
    xtype: 'component',
    id: 'myComponentId',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(me, eOpts) {
            var myObj = new SomeClass({
                "divID": this.id,
                "url": "data.json"
            });
        }
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'component',
    width: 30,
    style: {
        color: '#FFFFFF',
        backgroundColor: '#000000'
    }
}, {
    xtype: 'component',
    id: 'myComponentId2',
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(me, eOpts) {
            var myObj = new SomeClass({
                "divID": this.id,
                "url": "data2.json"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Afterrendering I am creating an object of a that class.

```
SomeClass = function(args) {
    var dataUrl = args.url;
    var divID = args.divID;
    var div = document.getElementById(divID);

    var myTable = '<input type="text" id="myInput"  list="myUL" myOpen = "openingList()" myOpen="openingList()" style="width:100% " >' +
        '<ul id="myUL" hidden=false>' + '<li>' + '<a href="#" ></a>' + '</li>' + '</ul>';
    div.innerHTML = myTable;

    function getData(callback) {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        httpRequest.open('GET', dataUrl, true);
        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (httpRequest.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && httpRequest.status === 200) {
                callback(httpRequest.responseText);
            }
        };
        httpRequest.send();
    }
    getData(function(data) {
        var jsonc = JSON.parse(data);
        var new_opt = "";
        for (i = 0; i < jsonc.length; i++) {
            new_opt += '<li><a href="#">' + jsonc[i]['VALUE'] + '</a></li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('myUL').innerHTML = new_opt;
    });
    myOpen = function() {
        var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
        ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
        ul.hidden = false;
        input = document.getElementById("myInput");
        filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
        var splitedVal = filter.split(";");
        filter = (splitedVal[splitedVal.length - 1]);
        li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
            if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
                li[i].style.display = "";
            } else {
                li[i].style.display = "none";

            }
        }
    }
    return div;
}
```

Now I am creating two object with two different divID for two different component. When I creating second object the data (which is coming from data.json) is getting lost and second object data is appeared. Also `ul` tag for the second objecte is not shown.

Can anybody help me to solve this. Or explain me where I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use ids inside a reusable component like this:

```
'<input type="text" id="myInput"

'<ul id="myUL"

document.getElementById('myUL')

document.getElementById("myInput")
```

IDs have to be global for the entire page, so you cannot reuse them.

What you may want to do is address these elements in a non-global way. Not sure what pure Javascript has to offer; IIRC, the ExtJS [`down()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-down) method only works on ExtJS objects.

Or you could add the id of the mother component to the ids you use, to make them unique:

```
'<input type="text" id="myInput-'+divID+'"

'<ul id="myUL-'+divID+'"

document.getElementById('myUL-'+divID)

document.getElementById("myInput"+divID)
```

Comment: can I use `class` instead of ID ?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at your code briefly it seems like you are loading your data and the displaying that data in 2 components. If so then you can simplify this code a lot. Please look at following examples. http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/examples/classic/view/data-view.html

This examples shows how to load the data via Ajax and then display in a component. Though I understand you have 2 components here but the concept is similar (decouple data and component).